# Run two websites with one laravel installation

Tags: laravel

How we can use multiple applications with one Laravel installation.

For example:
www.apple.com
www.orange.com

both website will use ONE CORE laravel installation with separate database and all other separate stuff.

Is that possible?
If yes then how?

Also I have done the same thing for CodeIgniter but not sure how i can do with 
laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use route group for this, it's something like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', 'Controller@Method');
});
```

Official documentation: [Sub-domain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules to better organize your code into it's separate websites within the same laravel base code. E.g. you can have Website1 and Website2 modules that has their own Controllers, Models, Views, database migrations, etc.